# Android: ScrollView is not scrolling after adding padding bottom/top

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have this vertical `ScrollView` with a title, sub-title, summary text, button and a footer.

Everything worked until I added to `<ScrollView>`:

```
    android:paddingTop="xxxx"
    android:paddingBottom="xxx"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```

After this, the page won't scroll even I can see the footer was been cut off. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks!!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:paddingTop="xxxx"
        android:paddingBottom="xxx"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:text="header"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subheader"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.04"
            android:layout_marginTop="xxx"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="xxx"
            android:layout_width="xxx"
            android:layout_height="xxx"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="xxxx"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_marginTop="xxxx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can only post image like this. Summary string might be very long so we need to scroll the whole page.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an image of your expected output?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed sorry I cannot post screenshot, but I posted a image to explain.

Comment: u havent closed the scrollview tag o.O

Comment: instead of adding xxxx how about adding some numbers O.o

Comment: @Zip Do you want to fix footer at bottom of your layout and the other parts are scrollable?

Comment: @Rico I actually close the ScrollView...Forgot to paste it. Numbers won't affect the scroll right? You can assume the summary string is really long.

Comment: @Ferdous Ahamed  I don't want it to fix, just scroll the whole page with some padding

Comment: why dont u use some tool like phonegap or xamarin , they are more flexible

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:text="This is a header"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subheader"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:text="Sub-header"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.04"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@id/subheader"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:text="This is summary. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque venenatis ex et elit tempus, lobortis iaculis justo fringilla. Nunc viverra porttitor elit id vestibulum. Phasellus mollis tempor ex, vitae accumsan nulla condimentum sed. Duis ullamcorper velit ut tempor rutrum. Cras vehicula facilisis tempor. Sed ut consequat enim. Aliquam scelerisque aliquet dapibus. Donec varius urna nec leo rhoncus, et suscipit sapien aliquam. Etiam ut eleifend enim, non viverra tellus. Aenean scelerisque dui ac consequat facilisis. Suspendisse augue odio, bibendum ut condimentum id, tristique id sapien. Curabitur lacus eros, consectetur hendrerit leo in, ullamcorper ultrices arcu. Mauris malesuada, ligula lobortis auctor iaculis, mauris eros imperdiet sapien, at vulputate urna quam non nibh. Sed erat mauris, fringilla ac risus sed, varius pulvinar ex."
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@id/summary"
            android:text="This is Footer"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]